# Value of type 'PromiseConstructor' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'? React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-typescript

`.then` not working in typescript.

```
interface Props {
  type: string;
  user: object;
  setUserAuth: Promise<any>;
}

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (type === "signup") {
      setUserAuth(type, { username: name, email, password })
        .then(() => history.push("/home"))
        .catch((err: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => setError(err));
    } else {
      setUserAuth(type, { email, password })
        .then(() => history.push("/home"))
        .catch((err: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => setError(err));
    }
  };
```

Promise:

```
export const setUserAuth = (type: string, userData: any) => (dispatch: any) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    apiCall("post", `/api/auth/${type}`, userData)
      .then(({ token, ...user }: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        setAuthorizationToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
        dispatch({
          type: SET_USER,
          payload: {
            user,
          },
        });
        resolve(user);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Error:

```
/home/vivek/Documents/Projects/Showcase Projects/fullstack-frontend/src/components/auth.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/vivek/Documents/Projects/Showcase Projects/fullstack-frontend/src/components/auth.tsx(23,20):
Value of type 'PromiseConstructor' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?  TS2348

    21 |     e.preventDefault();
    22 |     if (type === "signup") {
  > 23 |       setUserAuth(type, { username: name, email, password })
       |                    ^
    24 |         .then(() => history.push("/home"))
    25 |         .catch((err: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => setError(err));
    26 |     } else {
```

How can it be resolved...?

Answer (score 0):

`setUserAuth` is not a `Promise`. it's a function returning a promise.

it should be typed like this:

`setUserAuth: (type: SomeType, options: UserOptions) => Promise<any>`

(replace the argument types with the real types from your code)

Comment: what was the error? perhaps update the question?

Comment: modified the question.. I was trying to redirect the user to the home page after storing token in localstorage, using Promise.